# Generate HTML footnotes from in-text citations?

Tags: html, latex, markdown, footnotes, citations

I want to automatically create footnotes and ref-links (forward & *backward* if possible) to citations I add from reference managers (e.g. Sente, Mendeley, Papers). The best example are wiki-style numbered citations and footnotes with multiple back links. Before processing, my content looks like this:

> This is some text that has a reference. {Jones, 2005} And some more text with another reference {Smith, 2009} and a reference equal to the first {Jones, 2005}.

I'd like for a script or a software command to be smart enough to convert this to:

> This is some text that has a reference. [1] And some more text with another reference [2] and a reference equal to the first [1].
>
> 1. Jones, Source 1, 2005 [return to position 1 or 3]
> 2. Smith, Source 2, 2009 [return to position 2]

The

> {Jones, 2005}

key is what reference managers typically insert to refer to the entry in the database. When a document is scanned for keys, the ref managers output ordered in-text citations and bibliography in plain text, but I am not able to export into HTML with lists and links the way the Wikimedia tools can. Obviously, adding HTML superscript formatting, id's and links manually for each citation and reference is painful and error-prone.

I've tried Multimarkdown and Pandoc, but none provides a solution for multiple citations to the same footnote/reference (they generate new footnotes for each citation!) and proper back links to the last reading point (they only back link to the first citation to the same reference).

**Is there a script or a reference manager that can do this?**

Comment: Offtopic - try tex.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: As you've seen from the limited response to posting an identical version of this question tex, it is better asked here. As a note, you should not double post on different sites but instead ask for a question to be migrated from one site to another.

Comment: So where would it be best to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.1.0, [kramdown supports multiple footnote references](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#footnotes), including multiple backlinks.